# d3 x-axis label positioned below the x-axis

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm trying to draw an x-axis label for one of my d3 graphs, and I'm having a lot of trouble positioning it below the axis itself.  Here is my current code:

```
svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
     .append("text")
      .attr("x", (width / 2))
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Users ordered by contribution");
```

And here is a screenshot of the problem.  Is there a quick fix?

[image]

Comment: I don't see you setting the `y` attribute anywhere...something like `.attr("y",  height + margin.bottom)` assuming you have a margin. In any case, the `y` attribute is your friend here.

Comment: If I add that, then the label just disappears.

Comment: Oh... that's because my graph is being hidden.  Thanks.

Comment: @Hubrid You might need to make your `svg` larger. The `text` might just be too far down (in terms of coordinates).

Comment: Exactly-- that's what I just figured out.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .append("text")  
      .attr("x", (width / 2))
      .attr("y", height) //set your y attribute here
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Users ordered by contribution");
```

You can set your `y` position attribute for your `svg` text as per above